# How to test efficiently Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

I am working on an existing implementation of Dijkstra and one of my deliverable is to test whether this implementation is an efficient solution to the issue at hand or to recommend an alternate algorithm.
The question is... How should I baseline the existing Dijkstra algorithm so I could compare it to alternate?
To narrow the scope, my client is using Dijkstra to dynamically chose the best tariffs plan for b2b consumers. Does it make any sense?

Comment: "is an efficient solution to the issue at hand": can you describe what the issue is? Do you have information that can be exploited in another algorithm (like eg. A*).

Answer (score 2):

[Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is an algorithm to find the shortest path in a graph. To test and see how effective is that, you need to compare it with other algorithms. like [Bellman–Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm, [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) , etc.

### important notes

Other than performance, there are other important issues like Dijkstra doesn't work with negative values. That is why Bellman-Ford has been used instead in many problems.

Also, Dijkstra has different implementations.

Dijkstra's algorithm with list is from O(V 2) while Dijkstra's algorithm with modified binary heap is from O((E + V) log V) and Dijkstra's algorithm with Fibonacci heap is from O(E + V log V). Bellman–Ford algorithm is from O(VE).

### Conclusion

If you need to see which one is better for your work, first see which parameters matters for you and then compare the ones that can be suitable. If you want, you can even test them since they all have been implemented by other people before. You just need to give them a graph

Comment: Hi Ashkan, Thanks You for taking the time to reply. A funny thing is my client client is using Dijkstra to evaluate the best tariff plan for b2b consumer. I am not sure how this fit into Dijkstra. Have you seen this elsewhere?

Comment: @lucTiber you can map your plan as a graph, where each place is a node and each edge is the price of accessing from a node to the other. of course you can use Dijkstra when you know how much does it costs to access from 1 place to another

Comment: Thanks for The Time. Very much appreciated